# Impedance calculation of a four stage Dickson voltage multiplier

Tags: rf, energy-harvesting, multiplier, charge-pump

I built a four stage Dickson voltage multiplier for RF energy harvesting at 2.45 GHz. This is the circuit which I built.

[image]

My components are BAT54S as diode and 100uF capacitor. I need to calculate the impedance of my circuit.

The first thing that came to my mind to use power equation. **P = IoutxIoutxR**, but I am not sure if it works. During my research I came across with [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258714751_Impedance_optimization_of_wireless_electromagnetic_energy_harvester_for_maximum_output_efficiency_at_mW_input_power).

The author says that the impedance depends on frequency and input power. Frequency is understandable.

I have 2 questions about this topic.

1. Does the impedance of a voltage multiplier depend on the input power?
2. How can I calculate the impedance of this circuit?

Comment: I think you will find that 100uF capacitors don't work well at 2.5GHz.  They will act more like inductors at that frequency. As storage (the capacitors on the right) they'd be OK.  As coupling capacitors (the ones on the left) they'd probably block all the RF.  Charging the storage capacitors might take a pretty good while, as well.

Comment: @JRE When I was making research, I found out that capacitor must be more than the capacitance of diodes. The diode I'm using is BAT54S. It has 10pF capacitance. That's why I choose 100uF. What value should i use for coupling ones?

Comment: Consider NP0 ceramic surface-mount capacitors for all; they have very low dielectric loss.  Electrolytics are lossy (parallel resistance) enough to likely not charge at all.  And be careful of simulators - they don't model parasitics like component lead/trace inductance and this will certainly affect operation.

Comment: The exact value for the coupling capacitors depends on the impedance of the multipliers and the load.  The last time I built a high frequency multiplier, I used [Qucs](http://qucs.github.io/) and a model of the [BAT63 diodes](https://github.com/JosephEoff/RF-Concho/blob/master/datasheets/Infineon-BAT63SERIES-DS-v01_01-en.pdf) I was using to determine a good value for the coupling capacitors.  I ended up using 10pF, 0201 sized parts.  The junction capacitance of the BAT63 is less than1pF, so the 10 pF coupling capacitors are much larger.

Answer (score 6):

> *I built 4 stages Dickson voltage multiplier for RF energy harvesting
> at 2.45 GHz*

And

> *My components are BAT54S as diode and 100uF capacitor.*

In one of your [previous questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623788/capacitor-value-for-rf-energy-harvesting), you were given this in an answer: -

> *The capacitance of the BAT54S is far to high at 2.4 GHz, most of the
> received energy will be used to charge this capacitance, poor
> harvester. Pin diodes are much better there but have higher Ufwd. Try
> JDH2S02FS with 0.3 pF and 220 mV at 1 mA.*

So, if you went ahead with the BAT54S, the capacitance of 10 pF would have an impedance of 6.5 Ω reactive and be absolutely useless for this circuit. But, nevertheless, you ask what the input impedance will be and, presumably that is a question related to the operating frequency of 2.45 GHz.

Well, replace all the diodes with 10 pF capacitors because they won't work as diodes with that amount of capacitance at 2.45 GHz.

Next, using 100 μF capacitors is not going to prove at all successful either. Capacitors of this value will be net inductive probably around 10 MHz and have an inductance of about 5 nH. At 2.45 GHz, a 5 nH inductor will have an impedance of about 7.7 Ω and so you might as well model the diode/capacitor network as a bunch of 10 pF capacitors (replacing the diodes) and 5 nH inductors replacing the capacitors.

Push the circuit through AC analysis in a simulator and see what you get but, it's a pointless exercise with those chosen components.

Answer (score 4):

> I found out that capacitor must be more than the capacitance of diodes. The diode I'm using is BAT54S. It has 10pF capacitance. That's why I choose 100uF.

You chose a value 7 orders of magnitude larger, when all you needed was 1-1.5 orders of magnitude higher.

I’d start with something like 100pF for coupling. Once that works, it can get a couple times higher in small steps (x1.5 previous value) *only if* you can measure improvement by going higher.

Make sure those capacitors have self-resonant frequency (SRF) well above 2.5GHz. In fact, SRF is just as important as the minimum capacitance C. If you have *either* SRF or C too low, the circuit will not work well or at all.

You’ll find out that the coupling capacitors you need will likely be surface mount parts, although maybe some tiny disc ceramics would eke by.

Due to leakage, the 100uF capacitors in this application are probably fiction. Start with 1uF X7R ceramics, for as high a voltage as you can afford. If you can measure the leakage, so much the better.